# Can we attach a javascript file to a web browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have created a javascript file.
Is there a way to attach this file to a browser?
The javascript code should get executed in the background for any site that is opened in that browser.

Comment: Have a Look at greasemonkey

Comment: Do you want it for self-use? or to run on other users computer?

Comment: Which browser are we talking about? What does this JS file do? Have you looked at creating a browser extension instead?

Comment: Greasymonkey is all that I wanted.Thanks everyone!